# async retry yeilding Invalid Arguments when used from module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have multiple functions created inside module.exports
I'm trying to invoke async retry on a function which is trying to do a POST request to an API and wait for response. It will retry for 3 times with timeout of 200s.

But everytime i run it the first iteration is executed, its able to call the function sendEnergy and initaite a POST request. But on fail when its retrying its throwing error

> Error: Invalid arguments for async.retry

Here is my code-

```
module.exports = {
sendMessageToNewModel: (body, id) => {
    url = '';
    switch (id) {
      case 'energy':
        url = 'http://myapi.test.api/appliance'; //for appliance energy
        break;
      case 'device-energy':
        url = 'http://myapi.test.api/device'; //for device energy
        break;
    }
    async.retry({ times: 3, interval: 200 }, module.exports.sendEnergy(url, body), function (err, result) {
      console.log(result)
    });
  },

  sendEnergy: (url, body) => {
    const options = {
      url: url,
      json: true,
      body: body
    };
    request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
      if (!err) {
        return res.statusCode;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
async.retry({ times: 3, interval: 200 }, module.exports.sendEnergy(url, body), function (err, result) {
      console.log(result)
    });"
```

module.exports.sendEnergy(url, body) = invoke sendEnergy(url, body)

which return nothing

According to the doc, it must be a function.

Without changing the structure , i could think of one way right now.

```
let sendEnergyRetry = sendEnergy.bind(null,url,body);

async.retry({ times: 3, interval: 200 }, sendEnergyRetry , function (err, result) {
          console.log(result)
        });"
```